# How do you update an existing Bootstrap modal data-target?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to update an existing `data-target` with a `data-target="#testModal1"` to point to the `#testModal2` modal using jquery `.data`, but even after the data attribute change it still is linked to `#testModal1`

```js
//Jquery:

$('#testButton').data('target', '#testModal2')
```

```html
<!-- HTML: -->


<button id='testButton' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal1">
      Test
    </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="testModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style='display:none'>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Testing Testing 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="testModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style='display:none;'>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Testing Testing 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a typo in the comment. I had `$('#testButton')`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's look in the jQuery documetation what `.data()` is:

> ## [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
>
> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.
>
> ### `.data( key, value )`
>
> **Description**: Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements.
>
> - key
>
>   Type: `String`
>
>   A string naming the piece of data to set.
> - value
>
>   Type: Object
>
>   The new data value; it can be **any Javascript type** including Array or Object.

---

Using  `$('#testButton').data('target','#testModal2')` you will **not** modify the `data-target` attribute but you will store the string `"#testModal2"` in `"target"` field. Then `$('#testButton').data('target')` will return `"#testModal2"`.

It's true that `.data('key')` can be used to return the `data-key` attribute value. But you cannot set it using `.data('key', 'newValue'`).

To set an attribute value the most common and easy way is to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method.

So, the answer is easy: change `data` in `attr` and use `data-target` instead of `target`:

```
$('#testButton').attr('data-target','#testModal2');
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5TMF/150/)

Comment: And Bootstrap doesn't use `$.data()` to access the `data-*` attributes because fat doesn't like it (due to perf worries?): https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11100

Comment: @cvrebert You can use it to get `data-attr` values but you cannot use it to set them. That's why I prefer to use `attr()` instead of `data()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my friends, this worked:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1064" 
aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse" 
class="cliccable_submenu d-block position-relative 
text-dark text-uppercase collapsible-link py-2">Link</a>

$('a[data-target="#collapse1064"]').attr("aria-expanded","true");
```