# How I can Dynamically Create Bootstrap Modal using For loop Angular6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

```
<div *ngFor="let task of data ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="{{task.id}}">
    //HTMl Content
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code I am unable to add the data-target Dynamically for the button. i have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725281/how-do-you-update-an-existing-bootstrap-modal-data-target) but this is modifying for all the modals at once only and having same name.

Thanks for your Help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use `[attr.data-target]="'#MyModal'+task.id"` ... considering the data structure is:

```
this.data = [
       {id:1, buttonLabel: 'test label 1', modalBody: 'Demo Modal body contents #1' }
      ,{id:2, buttonLabel: 'test label 2', modalBody: 'Demo Modal body contents #2' }
      ,{id:3, buttonLabel: 'test label 3', modalBody: 'Demo Modal body contents #3' }
      ];
```

This would be the HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let task of data ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#MyModal'+task.id">
    Open modal
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhhr7k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html